# Can you call other segues from other view controllers?

Tags: ios, segue

So I have a delegate set up in one class which can potentially enter a segue. If I call this function from another view controller, will the segue be performed? Or can only view controllers directly connected to segues perform a segue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The segue is defined from one view controller to another, so you have to invoke from the view controller in which it is defined. A workaround is to simply push the view controller without using segues. You can instantiate your view controller, assuming you've given it a storyboard id.

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationController"];
```

Then, you push the view controller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```